# Jet: draw_indexed: Crash on iOS 9.2 device

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, metal

I am seeing this crash when adding a SKEmitterNode to a scene. Is there anyway to control the "index" through the interface or is it a Metal bug? I tried setting `YES` to the `PrefersOpenGL` flag in the info.plist, but it doesnt work.

```
2015-12-19 22:49:41.967 appname[4190:1827024] Jet: draw_indexed: indexType must be 'unsigned_int' or 'unsigned_short'
Assertion failed: (indexType == jet_component_type_unsigned_int || indexType == 
jet_component_type_unsigned_short), function draw_indexed, file /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/Jet/Jet-1.50.1/Jet/jet_context_Metal.mm, line 1275.
```

Comment: Looks suspiciously like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34378530/sprite-kit-game-crashes-on-game-over-only-on-tvos) tvOS error.

Comment: I'm getting a similar error, but on TVOS. Also, it is on this file `jet_context_OpenGL.mm` not Metal. How do you know it is because of an SKEmitterNode?

Comment: I have a very complex emitternode, that was created for iOS 8 in an old XCode. The same file has been opened in the various beta Xcodes leading up to Xcode 7. Along with the other spritekit bugs that plagued iOS 9, i think its related. It even crashes after the same duration in the particle sytem, so its definitely to do with the some particle index. Loading other particle files is fine.

Comment: @Helium3 When does it crash? When you are playing the game? Mine crashes on game over.

Comment: @Paul - I load a specific SKEmitterNode and it crashes after a few seconds.

Comment: Have the same crash problem with iOS 9.2. Found out, that it not crashes if I take out one specific looping SKEmitterNode... I'll keep you updated

Comment: In my case I just lowered the birthrate from one emitter from 200 to 100 and it's not crashing anymore. So this will be my quickfix... let's see if next iOS release fixes that

Comment: In case you are still stuck with this, try fiddling with the zPosition, I set the emitter's zPosition to 1 and that worked for me

Comment: migrating to openGL and c++, spritekit is a joke