# Mysterious spritekit crash after adding emitterNode without stacktrace

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skemitternode

I've recently added a particle emitter to my game project with the following lines:

```
let backgroundEmitter1 = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "BackgroundParticle1.sks")
backgroundEmitter1!.name = "BackgroundParticle1Node"
backgroundEmitter1!.position = centerOfScreen
backgroundEmitter1!.particlePositionRange = CGVectorMake(screenWidth, screenHeight)
backgroundEmitter1!.zPosition = backgroundZPosition
sceneCanvas.addChild(backgroundEmitter1!)
```

Everything worked percetly before adding this emitterNode. After adding it, game loads ok and the emitter works fine but on the moment I touch the screen (well really I'm in the simulator) the game crashes without a stacktrace or error message. All I get is this:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS {CODE=1, ADDRESS=0x0}
```

What could be the possible cause for this?

Comment: So if it crashes when you touch the screen what is the code from `touchesBegan` ?

Answer (score 0):

Stupid issue...Xcode 7 had somehow removed the breakpoint that logs all exceptions. The actual emitter problem is related to question [Jet: draw_indexed: Crash on iOS 9.2 device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34376283/jet-draw-indexed-crash-on-ios-9-2-device)